# Why a simple hello world program doesnt work java (error java.lang.unsupportedclassversion)

Tags: java

Is my first time with java and i dont know how to resolve this, i even tried to search online but nothing, here the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.63 seconds
```

And this is the code, pretty simple:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Ciao java!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not complete exception message. Please make sure to provide full information.

Comment: To code in java, you need `JDK`. Check if you have installed it or not.

Comment: The short answer is that the class is not in the classpath.  It is not obvious from the information in your question why this is the case. A full stacktrace may provide more insight.   How did you compile the code?  How are you executing the code?

Comment: oh sure, i edited with the complete traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your java compiler and interpreter versions are different.
see what is the output of

```
javac -version
java -version
```

You are most probably using an early (old) version of `java` *(JRE)* than `javac`.

A quick and easy fix would be completely removing `java` from the machine and then installing JDK again.